# Adding extra manager methods in Django ORM ERROR

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I'm adding new method in Manager objects django like code bellow, and error returning:

"AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'search'."

Can someone help me?

```
from django.db import models


class CourseManager(models.QuerySet):

 def search(self, query):
    return self.get_queryset().filter(
        models.Q(name__icontains=query) | \
        models.Q(description_icontains=query)
    )

class Course(models.Model):

 name = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
 slug = models.SlugField('Atalho')
 description = models.TextField('Descrição', blank=True)
 start_date = models.DateField(
    'Data de Início', null=True, blank=True
 )
 image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='courses/images', verbose_name='Imagem',
    null=True, blank=True
 )
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(
    'Criado em', auto_now=True
 )
 update_at = models.DateTimeField(
    'Atualizado em', auto_now=True
 )

 objects = CourseManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my question.
The CourseManager class has to inherit from models.Manager and not from models.QuerySet.